# goimports does not sort imports as expected

Tags: go, goimports

I have created dummy file (which is called `file1.go`) with chaotic imports statements:

```golang
package somepackage

import (
        "context"

        "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"

        "fmt"

        "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func PrintMe() {
        _ = context.Background()
        fmt.Println("this is from somepackage...")
        sqlx.Rebind(1, "")
        _ = uuid.UUID{}
}
```

Why goimports does not sort such imports and does not group it?

I run command as follows:

```
goimports file1.go
```

Comment: You separated the imports with empty lines, indicating that you want the grouping as-is.

Comment: @JimB thank you! Where did you get this? I could not find such information in documentation